# SQL Migration Assistant For Access

Tags: sql, migration

I have recently downloaded microsoft SQL migration assistant to migrate access tables to a SQL back end. The program was working fine for me last week up until today. Now when I add an access database to the migration assistant I get an error "The operating system is not currently configured to use this application" and I have to reboot my machine to get out of the software.

I have tried uninstalling the migration assistant and Office, then reinstalling both, and downloading Access 2016 runtime.

Does anyone have a workaround for this error?

I have also tried manually exporting the tables from access via the ODBC link but it will take me weeks to move all the data that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/using-dao-data-access-objects-api-fails-from-external-applications-b2537b71-63a4-495b-8d5f-8faf1d4d5470?WT.mc_id=365AdminCSH_SupportCentral

fix by 11th October 2022, as described in MS article: good news, it's not your fault...  :=)

Comment: Thanks kwen1x

I managed to get it working by rolling back to a previous version of Microsoft Office for now

Answer (score -1):

fyi: I just had an office update installed. The problem is fixed.

Comment: This should be an edit to your other answer.